# How to test function in $scope from different controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine for testing my AngularJS application. I have an Authenticaiton controller, which calls a function which I define in the scope from the Application controller. So:

**1. AppController**

```
$scope.setUser = function() {}
```

**2. AuthenticationController**

```
$scope.setUser(User);
```

I am testing the `AuthenticationController`, and setUser() is not inside the `scope` of `AuthenticationController`. How do I inject the scope/function from the `AppController`?

**The error message:**

```
TypeError: $scope.setUser is not a function
```

Should I mock the whole function? Is the structure smelly? What's the best way to do this?

EDIT:
In the real app, AuthenticationController gets injected into my dashboard-app.

**AuthenticationController:**

```
angular
  .module( 'authentication', [])
  .controller('AuthenticationController', AuthenticationController);

AuthenticationController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'AUTH_EVENTS', 'AuthenticationService'];
```

**Dashboard:**

```
angular
  .module('dashboard', [
    'authentication'
  ])
  .run(run);
```

**Info:** *Names are changed in my question to make it easier to understand.*

Comment: How does AuthenticationController have access to that scope in the real app?

Comment: I usually mock the scope in such a cases.

Comment: @Bimper good point. I'm injecting AuthenticationController inside my main module, dashboard. So I guess through this injection it has access?

Comment: @0xc0de can you give a link or code example of how to do this? I'm asking myself if I mock this, how can I get sure that everything is linked/injected in the right way? Maybe the code architecture should be different if testing seems to "hard".

Answer (score 0):

inject $rootScope into your controllers.

1. AppController :

   $rootScope.setUser = function() {}
2. AuthenticationController

   $rootScope.setUser();